# How to pass input value of type 'date' to a function which Calculates and updates age every second

Tags: javascript, html, date, input, calculator

I'm trying to create a live age counter which calculates & updates the age every second using setInterval(). It works with the predefined input but isn't working with the manual user input submitted through a date object. How to pass the input of type 'date' to the calculateAge() function I'm using.

```
//js file 
    function ageCalculator() {
        
        function startCal() {
            setInterval( function() {
                calculateAge();

            }, 1000);
        }
        function calculateAge() {
        

            var nowDate = new Date();
            // Example date of birth.
            var dob = document.getElementById("age-value");
            var dobDate = new Date(dob);
    
           
            
            var str = (years +":"+months+":"+weeks+":"+days+":"+hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
            document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = str;
           
        }
    
       return {
           startCal : startCal
       }
    }

var ageCalculatorInstance = ageCalculator();
//ageCalculatorInstance.startCal();
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Age calculator</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Age calculator</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="input-age">
            <label for="age-value">Enter your age</label>
            <input id="age-value" type="date" />
            <button type="submit" onclick="function startCal()">Calculate Age</button>
        </div>
        <div id="age">

        </div>
        
    </div>
    <script src='js/script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use document.getElementById('age-value').value and get the data entered by user

Comment: Also,Is this the right way to call a function?     `var form = document.getElementById('submit-form');      form.button.onclick() = function() {
    ageCalculatorInstance.startCal();
}`

Comment: You should not use keyword function in the call just the method name. onclick="method()"

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the date entered by the user:

```
const input = document.getElementById("age-value").value;
const dateEntered = new Date(input);
```

Comment: Also,Is this the right way to call a function?     `var form = document.getElementById('submit-form');                                               form.button.onclick() = function() {
    ageCalculatorInstance.startCal();
}    `

Answer (score 0):

Use document.getElementById("age-value").`value`

and call the function as `onclick="ageCalculatorInstance.startCal()"`